# Comparing the Current Date with Previous Dates

Tags: java

I am trying to compare two dates. My first date is:

```
Date previousDate ="Returns a date as 2011-12-09 in a gregorian date"
```

and the second date is my "current date", where I am getting my current date as:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
Date date=new Date();
```

When I am try to compare the current date with my previous date, I am only able to compare the year (or only the first thing in the pattern).

```
System.out.println("date"+previousDate.compareto(format(date));
```

I am able to get the out put as "1", as it is only comparing the year but not whole date.
Can any of you guys figure out what i am missing.I tried many approaches but couldn't succeed.please let me know if i can work out with this or i need a different solution.

Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what you actually want to do. If you want to compare two Dates, why are you comparing previousDate to "the year"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By

```
SimpleDateFormat(yyyy/mm/dd);
```

I guess you mean

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

But the important point is that by convention `compareTo` usually returns -1, 0 or 1.

Here's the implementation of Date#compareTo :

```
974     public int compareTo(Date anotherDate) {
975         long thisTime = getMillisOf(this);
976         long anotherTime = getMillisOf(anotherDate);
977         return (thisTime<anotherTime ? -1 : (thisTime==anotherTime ? 0 : 1));
978     }
```

Comment: The exact contract is: a negative int, 0 or a positive int. You cannot rely on the values being -1, 0 and 1

Comment: yeah this is what i have used SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");So is there any other way other can compare ,because the case was to compare and see the days doesnt exceed 30 days.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd yes but it's usually renormalized to -1, 0, 1 and that's the case for Date.

Comment: i checked out trying the pattern to mm/dd/yyyy,even then it returned only the  value for month as 8.

Comment: I hope you meant MM/dd/yyyy. But I don't understand what's your precise goal.